# Selenium explicit wait set custom call interval?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using the following code [from here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) (C# version):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
        return d.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement"));
    });
```

The documentation below that snippet says:

> WebDriverWait by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully.

How can the code here be modified to include a different wait time, for example 10 milliseconds?

Answer (score 5):

You can set the polling interval for a specific instance of WebDriverWait, the below code will wait 20 seconds to locate the element and poll every 200 milliseconds.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);

IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
return d.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement"));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The [DefaultWait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_DefaultWait_1.htm) has polling interval.

```
DefaultWait<IWebDriver> wait = new DefaultWait(driver);
wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
```

Comment: Can you please include the `FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement"));` part as shown in my original sample? I'm probably doing something wrong but I get the error `Using the generic type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait<T>' requires 1 type arguments` when I replace your code with line 1 in my code. I have tried several things, but I'm not yet advanced enough to know how to fix that.

Comment: @Keavon, Have you tried the answer from [MatthewThomasGB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4638372/matthewthomasgb) below? The given answer should remove the error since the `WebDriverWait` class does not use generic type

Comment: @dey.shin I have not tried it because this project has long since ended, years ago.